# Padding adds to div width / height?

Tags: css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    * { margin:0; border:0; padding:0; }
    div { height:500px; }
    #container { width:1000px; background-color:#000; }
    #column-one { float:left; padding:10px; width:500px; background-color:#234; }
    #column-two { float:left; padding:10px; width:500px; background-color:#345; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="column-one">
    </div>
    <div id="column-two">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Counterintuitive indeed.

Comment: err is there a question?  And what browser (IE is notorious for this, it has a "busted" box model).

Comment: all browsers add padding, margin and borders to the element width/height

Comment: This is a well known "feature". What's your question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [content-box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html) states that padding and borders don't count in the `width` that you set for a box. So they add on to its `width`.

Modern browsers support CSS3's [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) to cause `width` to represent the total width of content, padding and borders (the default is, of course, `content-box`, triggering the above behavior).

Comment: I know this is old, and a topic that is beaten to death, but *why* does the content-box model not include padding?  It would be *much* easier to create precise layouts if I could specifically control the size of my divs and still have padding in them.  Also, I don't seem to be having any luck in either IE10 or Chrome with the "box-sizing" attribute.  Sorry if I sound frustrated.  It's not your fault.

Comment: @Mike U: That's because content cannot appear in the padding area by definition. Firefox has an experimental `padding-box` value, which is mentioned in the spec but is at-risk and not implemented anywhere else. There must be something else at play if you can't get box-sizing to work on IE10 or Chrome, because as far as I know, they both support it unprefixed.

Comment: I understand *how* the box model works. Mostly just curious *why* it works that way. It seems so unintuitive and illogical. I have gotten the box-model attribute to work since my previous comment. Seems that you can't just apply it to specific classes. Only way I got it to work was to apply it to "*". The classic way just seems illogical. If I want something to be 40% of the screen, and have a padding of 4px, that's impossible to do proper layout with the classic model. just a gripe, I guess. At least I know how to get around it, now.

Comment: @MikeU thats why CSS3 isn't the same as CSS2; plus, as we all know, CSS is broken

Answer (score 1):

The width is the width your content can fill, not the width of the box delimited by your border.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood but I think you can solve your problem by using `width: auto` for the div instead of `width: 100%`;
PS: I know the post is old but maybe still can be useful...